# defining < operator for map of list iterators

Tags: c++, list, stl, comparison, dictionary

I'd like to use iterators from an STL list as keys in a map.  For example:

> using namespace std;
>
> `list<int> l`;
>   `map<list<int>::const_iterator, int> t;`
>
> int main(int argv, char * argc) {
>    l.push_back(1);
>    t[l.begin()] = 5;
>   }

However, list iterators do not have a comparison operator defined (in contrast to random access iterators), so compiling the above code results in an error:

/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_function.h:227: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x < __y’

If the list is changed to a vector, a map of vector const_iterators compiles fine.

What is the correct way to define the operator < for list::const_iterator?

Comment: What for? Quite a strange contraption you have there. :)

Comment: The above is minimal and somewhat pointless example, but in my real program I have a std::list of objects (it's a list because I need to be able to remove elements from the middle quickly), and I'm building some other data structures that need to point to and from different points in that list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameterise `map` with a custom comparator:

```
struct dereference_compare {
    template <class I>
    bool operator()(const I& a, const I& b) {
        return *a < *b;
    }
};
map<list<int>::const_iterator, int, dereference_compare> t;
```

Comment: Just for ease of use, I'd rename it "dereference_compare" and move the template to the `operator()`. Take `I` as a `const&`.

Comment: Note that the map will be unordered from the list point of view, that is, given two iterators `i1` and `i2`, with the former preceding the later, it is undefined whether `i1` is closer to the beginning of the list than `i2` (this would be different with a vector)

Comment: @David, a vector would make no difference. The comparator compares by the iterator's target, not by the iterator itself. Worse, the map can hold iterators from different containers (though that isn't the intended use by the OP).